# Printing images on multi-page SSRS RDLC report does not work

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, rdlc

I am working on an application that loads a generic list of objects into an RDLC report, which is then rendered on the client machine using the `WebForms` `ReportViewer Control`. It renders fine and exports fine, but if I try to print it, it spools maybe 500k to the printer and then stops responding.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems to be a hardware problem!

Since you add a image control to your RDLC report it should work very well. 
I have created many RDLC forms, with images on header, and everything is fine.

You should always check if printer has some kind of issue and test it against another ones.